# Get value through one of the xmlnode property for currentnode

Tags: vb.net, xmlnode

My current xml node is :

```
<Item xsi:type="itm:Resource">
<ID>10</ID>
</Item>
```

I want to read the whole tag and search whether Resource is there or not in that tag :

```
SelectSingleNode.OuterXml.Contains("Resource")
```

But Outer xml is considering all the tags inside Item , I just want for the current node

Have tried other properties like name,value which indeeds return only "Item"

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in a slightly different way
`SelectSingleNode("xPath").Attributes(0).Value.Contains("Resource")` 
Hope this helps